# Не работает вёрста в библиотеке html2pdf

Tags: php, pdf

Использую библиотеку `html2pdf` для перекодировки `html->pdf`, проблема заключается в вёрстке:

```
    $content = "
<page>
<link type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/>
   <div class='top'>От кого:</div>
   <div class='feed'>тут какой-то текст<br></div>
   <div class='adres2'>Тут тоже какой-то текст</div>
   <div class='towhom'>
       Кому:".$fio."
</div>
<div class='adres'>
      Адрес:" .$item['post_index'].', '.$item['adress']."
</div>
   <img style='width:34%;' src='../img/logo_only.png'>
</page>";
```

При генерации игнорируются многие функции в вёрстке, даже обычные теги типа выделения текста `<strong>`, `<b>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документации к этой библиотеке написано, что html-файлы для нее нужно писать отдельно, произвольные готовые html-файлы не обработаются. То есть, нужно убедиться в том, что нужные вам функции форматирования поддерживаются, ознакомившись с документацией.

Это достаточно логично, поскольку весь спектр современных возможностей html/css обработает только современный браузер, а его запихнуть в небольшую php-библиотеку не выйдет.

Пример с жирным шрифтом (style='font-weight: bold')

```
<?php
require("html2fpdf.php");
$buffer = "
<h1>Hello Friends</h1><br>
<span style='font-weight: bold; font-size: 18pt; color: #FF0000; font- 
family: Times'>Hello there! I am red!<br></span>
<br>
<p style='font-size:10'>This is a sample code</p>
<p style='font-size:10px; color:blue;'>This is a sample code</p>
<span style='font-size:10px; color:blue;'>This is a sample code</p>
<span style='font-weight: italic; font-size: 10pt; color: #00FF00;'>I am a pdf ! Please accept my answer!</span>
 ";
 $pdf = new HTML2FPDF('P', 'mm', 'Legal');
 $pdf->AddPage();
 $pdf->WriteHTML($buffer);
 $pdf->Output('my.pdf', 'D');

  ?>
```

Этот пример взят отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44962676/5152519

Comment: то есть просто подключить отдельно html файл ?

Comment: Нет-нет, посмотрите, пожалуйста, примеры использования здесь https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/examples/example00.php

Comment: в этом примере ничего нет, но в других видно то что разделают страницу <page>

Comment: или подскажите как хотя бы сделать жирный шрифт, 2 дня уже мучаюсь

Comment: Посмотрите, я обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое :3